# Can I Copy a hard drive through ssh?

Tags: ssh

Can I copy an entire hard drive of one computer in one go over ssh? 
I have an old windows machine that I am ready to put Linux on but I would like to backup its contents.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The command you're looking for is `scp`

```
scp -r username@remotehost:/disk /some/local/directory
```

Note the `-r` flag to make it transfer directories recursively.

https://linux.die.net/man/1/scp

It transfers files over ssh.